# What's way to get the cyclomatic complexity of a file using sonar rest api?

Tags: sonarqube

I have checked in some files under svn and run a nightly build to publish the report for those files on Sonar dashboard.
Now I have some custom reporting which use cyclomatic complexity of those files from sonar using api.

As I checked there is a rest api to get the CC from resource ID but I don't have that also because info which is available that is only file name with absolute path.
So if I go for current rest api then first how may I get resource id for that particular file then I can get CC for that file using another api.

Someone can help me to get the CC using resources or file name by using rest api.

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify your version of the platform, so I'll assume the latest & recommend the resource API.

http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources/index gives you a list of projects - with id's

You can set *depth* to -1 to see all children, and add the list of *metrics* you want included, to get complexity and whatever else you need.
E.G. http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources/index?resource=808785&depth=1&metrics=complexity

**EDIT**

Here's what the docs say about *depth*:

> Used only when resource is set:
>
> - 0: only selected resource
> - -1: all children, including selected resource
> - >0: depth toward the selected resource
>
> Default value: 0
> Example value: -1

Essentially, in your project tree, *depth* determines how many levels of children to retrieve from the specified *resource*.

Comment: Thanks...as if now I can get useful info which require for reporting. But to understand whats the concept of depth here...